# CSS3 Animating Scale Property not working on non webkit browsers

Tags: css

Have been wracking my brains over this all morning. Am using CSS3 background gradient on a div together with a scale transition to give the illusion of a progress bar effect. I have only been able to get it working on webkit browsers. All the others display the end result from the start. Any idea please?

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style>
#grad1
{
position:absolute;
top:10px;
left:10px;
height:30px;
width:110px;
visibility:visible;

background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #EF8E76, #E54D26);
background: -moz-gradient(right, #EF8E76, #E54D26);
background: -o-linear-gradient(right, #EF8E76, #E54D26);
background: linear-gradient(to right, #EF8E76, #E54D26);

-webkit-animation: grow 10s linear 0s 1;
-moz-animation: grow 10s linear 0s 1;
-o-animation: grow 10s linear 0s 1;
-ms-animation: grow 10s linear 0s 1;
animation: grow 10s linear 0s 1;

}
@-webkit-keyframes grow {
0% { -webkit-transform: scale(0,1);-webkit-transform-origin: 0% 0%; visibility:hidden;}
10% { -webkit-transform: scale(0,1);-webkit-transform-origin: 0% 0%; visibility:visible;}
100% { -webkit-transform: scale(1,1);-webkit-transform-origin: 0% 0%; visibility:visible;}
}

@-moz-keyframes grow {
0% { -webkit-transform: scale(0,1);-moz-transform-origin: 0% 0%; visibility:hidden;}
10% { -webkit-transform: scale(0,1);-moz-transform-origin: 0% 0%; visibility:visible;}
100% { -webkit-transform: scale(1,1);-moz-transform-origin: 0% 0%; visibility:visible;}
}

@-o-keyframes grow {
0% { -webkit-transform: scale(0,1);-o-transform-origin: 0% 0%; visibility:hidden;}
10% { -webkit-transform: scale(0,1);-o-transform-origin: 0% 0%; visibility:visible;}
100% { -webkit-transform: scale(1,1);-o-transform-origin: 0% 0%; visibility:visible;}
}

@-ms-keyframes grow {
0% { -webkit-transform: scale(0,1);-ms-transform-origin: 0% 0%; visibility:hidden;}
10% { -webkit-transform: scale(0,1);-ms-transform-origin: 0% 0%; visibility:visible;}
100% { -webkit-transform: scale(1,1);-ms-transform-origin: 0% 0%; visibility:visible;}
}

@keyframes grow {
0% { -webkit-transform: scale(0,1);transform-origin: 0% 0%; visibility:hidden;}
10% { -webkit-transform: scale(0,1);transform-origin: 0% 0%; visibility:visible;}
100% { -webkit-transform: scale(1,1);transform-origin: 0% 0%; visibility:visible;}
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="grad1"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are using -webkit-transform everywhere ...

Answer (score 1):

As @vals said in the comments, you are using the `-webkit` prefix for all the `transform` properties in the different animation declarations.

If you update your CSS to the following it should work:

```
@-moz-keyframes grow {
    0% {
        -moz-transform: scale(0, 1);
        -moz-transform-origin: 0% 0%;
        visibility:hidden;
    }
    10% {
        -moz-transform: scale(0, 1);
        -moz-transform-origin: 0% 0%;
        visibility:visible;
    }
    100% {
        -moz-transform: scale(1, 1);
        -moz-transform-origin: 0% 0%;
        visibility:visible;
    }
}
@-o-keyframes grow {
    0% {
        -o-transform: scale(0, 1);
        -o-transform-origin: 0% 0%;
        visibility:hidden;
    }
    10% {
        -o-transform: scale(0, 1);
        -o-transform-origin: 0% 0%;
        visibility:visible;
    }
    100% {
        -o-transform: scale(1, 1);
        -o-transform-origin: 0% 0%;
        visibility:visible;
    }
}
@-ms-keyframes grow {
    0% {
        -ms-transform: scale(0, 1);
        -ms-transform-origin: 0% 0%;
        visibility:hidden;
    }
    10% {
        -ms-transform: scale(0, 1);
        -ms-transform-origin: 0% 0%;
        visibility:visible;
    }
    100% {
        -ms-transform: scale(1, 1);
        -ms-transform-origin: 0% 0%;
        visibility:visible;
    }
}
@keyframes grow {
    0% {
        transform: scale(0, 1);
        transform-origin: 0% 0%;
        visibility:hidden;
    }
    10% {
        transform: scale(0, 1);
        transform-origin: 0% 0%;
        visibility:visible;
    }
    100% {
        transform: scale(1, 1);
        transform-origin: 0% 0%;
        visibility:visible;
    }
}
```

Note: if you don't change the `transform-origin` values in your animation you should remove them.

Comment: Hi, That's great - I can't believe I missed that - think I was staring at it too long!

The transform-origin values are there to make the growth happen from left to right. If I don't specify them in the animation the gradient grows left and right. Perhaps I could specify them in the initial CSS - I'm not sure if that's possible